# Bootstrap vertical button group with alerts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a vertical button group using Bootstrap (2). I would like the buttons the same width, and the alerts to the right. Is it possible? This is what I got so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/tnrx53ss/

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div id="myButtons" class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <input class="newSurveyInput" type="hidden" id="Size" name="Size" value="Liten" />
                <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default active">First</button><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Alert text regarding First.</div>
                <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default">Second</button><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Some other text about Second.</div>
                <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default">Third</button><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Third option explained</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use Bootstrap 2.x?

Comment: I'm afraid so, but we can use columns.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. Add bootstrap classes as below. If you don't know about bootstrap grid system go through a bootstrap tutorial and understand the grid system.

```
<div class = "container" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <div id="myButtons" class="btn-group-vertical row" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <input class="newSurveyInput col-md-12" type="hidden" id="Size" name="Size" value="Liten" />
      <div class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default active col-md-6  col-sm-6">First</button>
         <div class="alert alert-info col-md-6  col-sm-6" role="alert">Alert text regarding First.</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default  col-md-6  col-sm-6">Second</button>
         <div class="alert alert-info  col-md-6  col-sm-6" role="alert">Some other text about Second.</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <button type="button" onclick="$('input#Size').val(($(this).html()))" class="btn btn-default col-md-6  col-sm-6">Third</button>
         <div class="alert alert-info col-md-6  col-sm-6" role="alert">Third option explained</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP stated they're using Bootstrap 2

Comment: @Skelly This works fine in bootstrap 2 as well. I checked.

Comment: It doesn't work according to the question. There are no `col-*` classes in BS 2. http://bootply.com/1JGgyIn1mM